# Azure VHD Backup?

Tags: powershell, azure, vhd

I am following this script http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Script-Sample-0daf6d9d for backing up vhds. I modified the backup.ps1 to meet my needs but I am having some problems. When I ran the script it would always fail on

Set-AzureSubscription -DefaultSubscription $SubscriptionName

it says

Set-AzureSubscription : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'DefaultSubscription'.

So I commented it out and ran it. Everything else runs great but it backs up to the wrong container. So why is it doing this? And how do I get it to backup to a place I specify?

Also at the beginning of the script it has Param($ServiceName, $VMName) , how do I pass these to this? Do I use a batch file? I have been setting them manually but I would love to pass them. I just have no idea how. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Set-AzureSubscription to specify which subscription you're working on. Do you have certificate for the subscription? Or do you have name of it?

Comment: Yes I have the name of it, what do you mean by certificate? I did the Add-AzureAccount and tied my credentials to it. it just seems off that that command does not work. I suppose I could set it every time and not worry about the default.

Comment: This command is used to set your subscription, so all other commands will not require you to enter it each time. As I understand it saves information in the Windows Registry. Looks like calling convention was changed after script was published. That's all.

Comment: Thanks, I have been finding in Azure stuff seems to change pretty quickly and often so sometimes the scripts I find are not always accurate. Thanks for the clarification.